How do I create a moving uilabel in swift?
I added a label and made the label move when the button is clicked.
It works fine up to one
However, if you create a second label, the first label you created will return to its original position.
Can I create a new label while maintaining the existing location?
    @IBAction func btnTextAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vMain.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vMain.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vMain.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.view != nil else { return }

        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        
        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
    }


@Sweepe - If you remove the center constraint, the label will be created in the upper left corner. I want the position where the existing label was moved to remain unchanged even if I create a new label.

@Sweeper - Thank you for answer
I'm not sure as I'm a beginner. Could you please tell me in more detail?

@Sweeper - And vMain is the top view.

You added constraints to constrain the centre of the label to be the centre of vMain, so when a new label is added, everything is laid out again according to the constraints, and therefore the label is positioned back to the centre again.
If you only want the label to initially be in the centre, just set its center directly:
@IBAction func btnTextAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hello"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.sizeToFit()
    vMain.addSubview(label)
    label.center = vMain.center
    
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

Alternatively, you can remove the constraints in handlePanGesture, i.e. when the view is dragged for the first time.
@objc func handlePanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let draggedView = sender.view else { return }

    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(view.constraints.filter { $0.firstItem as? NSObject == draggedView })
    draggedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
}

